# Possible Reasons for the Discrepancy in Trainable Parameters of the Extended DeepConvLSTM Model

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

I have implemented **DeepConvLSTM** baseline Model input are 60×d frames each representing 60 samples with d features. Frames are fed into four consecutive convolution layers with standard rectified linear units (Fig. 2). Input frames are obtained through a standard sliding window procedure (window length: 60; shift: 30). Convolution filters of size 5×1 in all convolution layers expand the 24×d input frame to a two-dimensional array of size 44 × (d × f), where d is the number of features and f (set to 64) denotes the number of filters in each convolution layer. This sequence of 44 resulting feature vectors is then modeled by a two-layer LSTM with 128 hidden units. The final hidden layer of the LSTM represents the embedding of the input frame, which is fed into a linear layer and a softmax to produce the prediction for an input frame.

"I have computed the trainable parameters for the DeepConvLSTM model and compared them with the reported trainable parameters in a research paper. Both sources confirm that the number of trainable parameters for this model is exactly the same, amounting to 1.73 million. This finding provides reassurance that everything is proceeding smoothly and without any discrepancies at this stage."

Now, we further **extend DeepConvLSTM by incorporating the attention mechanism**; we analyze the 44 hidden states of the LSTM that represent the embeddings for the different parts of an input frame. We consider the first 43 hidden states as the historical temporal context and learn 43 weights corresponding to these states:

past context = [h1,h2,h3,...h43] (Eq.1)

current = h44 (Eq.2)

transformed context = tanh(W1 ×past context+b1) (Eq.3)

weights = softmax(W2 ×transformed context+b2) (Eq.4)

final embedding = past context×weights+current (Eq.5)

Where b1 and b2 denote the biases in the two linear layers, and W1 and W2 represent the 2D matrices in the linear layers. We initially apply a linear transformation accompanied by a tanh linearity, transforming each of these seven vectors of size 128 into seven new vectors of size 128 (Eq. 3). Another linear transformation converts these 43 vectors each to size 1 essentially giving us scores for each of the hidden states. These scores are then passed through a softmax to give the final set of weights (Eq. 4). These weights are used to calculate a weighted sum of all the 43 hidden states to give the final embedding for the past context. This past context is added to the last hidden state to give the final embedding for the input frame (Eq. 5). This final embedding is used for classification as opposed to the last hidden state used by DeepConvLSTM.

"Upon computing the trainable parameters for the extended model of DeepConvLSTM, I have discovered a notable discrepancy compared to the reported figures in the research paper. After incorporating an Attention layer into the DeepConvLSTM architecture, the parameter count for my implemented model has increased to 1.75 million. However, the baseline model in the research paper reports a parameter count of approximately 2.5 million on the same dataset. This significant difference raises concerns and prompts the need for a thorough examination of the situation to identify the underlying problem. Can anyone dive into the details and explore the possible reasons for this discrepancy."